Wordpress theme-editor.php:Sorry, that file cannot be edited
In worpdress I need to open Theme File editor and when I try to do that: Wordpress=>Appearance=>Theme File editor I receive an error message:Sorry, that file cannot be edited.
/wordpress/wp-admin/theme-editor.php
I don't know how can I fix it? I use xampp for localhost.
Reinstalled wordpress and db, still not working

Could you please ensure that the file permissions for your theme files are correctly set up. WordPress needs write permissions to edit theme files.

Also please check if your wp-config.php file has that code. If it has that code then please remove it.
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);

WordPress added this to /includes/functions.php at some point.
// Normalize path for Windows servers
$file = wp_normalize_path( $file );

Although I am running Apache on my Windows desktop, that causes the same problem.  If I comment that line out, it works.

Check these support tickets related to this issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/help-i-cannot-access-theme-editor-file/ & https://wordpress.org/support/topic/when-trying-to-open-the-theme-editor-from-under-worpdress-a-message-appears-so/
